# Full screen image that scales

Tags: css, image, fullscreen

I am trying to create a home page that has an image that covers the entire screen, I followed a tutorial and got something like what I want, but it doesnt show the entire image.

I see a lot of sites that do this so it must be possible, I have an image that spans the entire screen but the image doesnt really scale to fit the browser, the bottom of the image is trimmed off.

```
html{               
            /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
            min-height:100%;    
            position:relative;          
        }

        body {
            background:url('bg.jpg') center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;

            /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
            min-height:100%;

            font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;    

        }
```

My image is bigger than the browser viewport but it doesnt get scaled so the whole image can fit, instead the bottom is chopped off.

HOw can I get it to scale with the browser? I am using bootstrap if there is anything there that can help.

Comment: The question is, is it allowed for the image to be stretched in one direction? If not, what is supposed to happen if the screen doesn't have the same shape as the image?

Comment: Some of the sites you are talking about will do one of two things; 1) Crop the image in some way (most likely) or 2) stretch/compress the image along one or both axis. These are happening and you probably haven't noticed. If the browser viewport has a ratio of 4:3, but your image is 16:9, something has got to give as the two are not the same. You'll either crop the image or stretch/compress the image.

Comment: Well when I tried using an image tag sized to the page it looked stretched.. so is the answer to have a cropped image for smaller screen sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. Choose which one suits you best.

1. If you want the image to be all visible and to fill all of the background, use `background-size:100vw 100vh` or `100% 100%`.
   Note: This will distort the image if it's not the same shape as the window.

   ```css
       html {
         height:100%;
         background:#CCC url(http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500) center no-repeat;
         background-size:100vw 100vh;
       }
   ```
2. To have your image fill the screen without distortion, you can use `cover`.
   Note: this will crop the image if it's not the same shape as the window.

   ```css
       html {
         height:100%;
         background:#CCC url(http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500) center no-repeat;
         background-size:cover;
       }
   ```
3. To have your image be the largest possible size without cropping or distorting, use `contain`.
   Note: this will not fill the whole window if the image is not the same shape.

   ```css
       html {
         height:100%;
         background:#CCC url(http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500) center no-repeat;
         background-size:contain;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. While this question has been asked before, I couldn't find one with complete answers (with clear examples), so I just had to write one myself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can see other manners to solve this here:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I hope that I can help you.

Comment: That is what I am using.